# Ошибка в выводе бинома ньютона(c++)

Tags: c++, математика, комбинаторика

Написал программу для вычисления бинома Ньютона. При вводе аргумента в диапазоне [1,13] все работает. Если вводить больший аргумент, то программа работает неправильно. В чем проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int fact(int n) {
    int k = 1;
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        k = k*i;
    return k;
}

void func(int n) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
            cout << (fact(j) / (fact(i)*fact(j - i))) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    func(n);
    system("pause");
}
```

Также [вот](http://ideone.com/ix5tpZ) вариант в онлайн компиляторе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

13! = 6227020800

14! = 87178291200

int (4 байта) имеет диапазон [−2147483648; +2147483647], поэтому числа просто не влезают

Чтобы расширить возможности, не меняя алгоритма, можно поменять тип на unsigned long long (8 байт)

Comment: Не совсем так, хотя это верно для 99% случаев. Размер `int` всегда был равен машинному слову, однако для 64-разрядных систем однако оставили его размер 4 байта для совместимости, [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5_%28%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%29#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5) утверждает, что могут быть и 8-байтные `int`

Answer (score 5):

У вас происходит так называемое переполнение типа. `int` имеет ограниченный диапазон значений (обычно от `−2147483648` до `+2147483647` знаковый, либо от `0` до `4294967295`, если беззнаковый). В случае переполнения значение "перескакивает" от максимального к минимальному (при сложении и умножении положительных чисел), это связанно с удобством аппаратной реализации, но в целом это явление называется неопределённым поведением (`undefined behavior`) и когда подобное происходит, то компилятор снимает с себя всю ответственность за корректность выполнения такой программы.

Вы можете использовать типы, которые имеют более широкий диапазон значений (например `unsigned long long` размером 8 байт и имеющий диапазон значений от `0` до `18446744073709551615`).

В случае, если требуемое значение всё равно не помещается в диапазон, то можно сделать свою реализацию длинной арифметики либо использовать библиотечные реализации (учитывайте, что эти библиотеки не являются сандартными, их нужно отдельно скачивать)

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
boost::multiprecision::cpp_int very_long_number;
// или
#include <gmpxx.h>
mpz_class very_long_number;
```

в этих случаях диапазон значений ограничивается лишь размером вашей оперативной памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Работа по обычной формуле - через факториал: для `int` в 4 байта - предел - 13, для `unsigned long long` в 8 байт - 21. При этом для `int` сам бином вполне записывается до 17 степени, для `unsigned long long` - до 29 (т.е. все коэффициенты помещаются в указанные типы).

Если сокращать дробь сразу по ходу вычислений - то и куда больше... Так что рекомендовал бы такой способ вычислений (в компиляторе, где не реализован `gcd`, легко написать самостоятельно:

```
unsigned long long C(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long m)
{
    unsigned long long q = 1, d = 1;
    for(; m < n;)
    {
        d *=(n-m);
        q *= ++m;
        unsigned long long z = gcd(q,d);
        q/= z; d /= z;
    }
    assert(d == 1);
    return q;
}
```

Сокращение на НОД позволяет частично избегать переполнения. По крайней мере C_50^25 берет легко без всяких переполнений :) Предел применимости - до `N = 63` включительно ([проверено](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/master/exper/C_n%5Em.cpp) :))

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не надо лучше считать факториалы - слишком сильно Вы себя ограничиваете в вычислении коэффициентов. При их вычислении бОльшая часть сокращается. Я бы либо придумал систему сокращения числителя и знаменателя или, что проще, строить треугольник паскаля (здесь да, придется 1 раз потратить ресурсы, зато потом вычисление коэффициентов будет О(1))

P.S. можно рекурсивно всегда вычислять коэффициент через предыдущие по известной формуле.

Comment: Каждый раз считать факториалы, делить их - слишком затратно. Лучше действительно посчитать и запомнить (причеи при построении треугольника паскаля нужно только сложение). Память дешевая, время процессора - дорогое.